# Gradle build failing with 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'

Tags: java, ssl, gradle

I have a Java application which is developed and built with `gradle`.

I have an issue when running `gradle build`, the build fails with the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':jar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compile'.
   > Could not download client-java-api.jar (io.kubernetes:client-java-api:5.0.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/kubernetes/client-java-api/5.0.0/client-java-api-5.0.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/kubernetes/client-java-api/5.0.0/client-java-api-5.0.0.jar'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The error is thrown for all the dependencies.

I've ensured that I imported the jcenter certificate into the cacerts:

```sh
keytool -import -alias "ADD_CERTIFICATE_ALIAS" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file "PATH\TO\CERTIFICATE\CERTIFICATE.cer"
```

I verified the certificate was imported there as well (output of 
`keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts`):

```
...
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): B8:23:6B:00:2F:1D:16:86:53:01:55:6C:11:A4:37:CA:EB:FF:C3:BB
jcenter, Oct 30, 2019, trustedCertEntry, 
...
```

I also changed the gradle script in `C:\Gradle\bin\gradle.bat` and added `%GRADLE_OPTS%`/`%JAVA_OPTS%` the trustStore as an argument so now the `gradle build` command is the following:

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java.exe"   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\security\cacerts" "-Dorg.gradle.appname=gradle" -classpath "C:\Gradle\bin\..\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain bui
ld`

As an FYI, this issue doesn't occur when I am not behind a VPN (ZScaler).

**UPDATE**
I ran the following command:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect jcenter.bintray.com:443`

And it showed the following line which probably related:

`verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`

Any other ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you try to download the jar file by typing in the browser with this url https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/kubernetes/client-java-api/5.0.0/client-java-api-5.0.0.jar

Comment: Yep, sorry, didn't mention but I can download it with other clients (`curl`, browser) so it seems to indicate that I'm doing something incorrectly with JVM/Gradle.

Comment: Is this a corporate VPN with a man-in-the-middle proxy?  If so, then you will need to add the corporate certificates to the trust store as well.

Comment: What version of Java were you running ? I mean which exact version, like 1.8.0_241-b07

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Import Zscaler Root Certificate into Java System Truststore

```
sudo keytool -import -alias zScaler -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file /Users/code/Zscaler_Root_CA.cer
```

### Longer explanation

The purpose of Zscaler is protect/ inspect/ audit all the network traffic for your corporations peace of mind, compliance, due diligence etc., etc. When you connect to VPN, this is a more trusted environment and your corporation may have policy that changes the behavior of Zscaler.

Zscaler will dynamically man in the middle and proxy all the SSL connections you make in your browser. Your IT department have likely pushed the Zscaler root certificate into your machine, so it is available to be trusted when you browse.

Your issue stems from trying to run a gradle command that is executed by an underlying Java JVM. This Java install ships with a set of certificates that are trusted. Zscaler is not in that list.

Given the corporation is unlikely to relent on its use of Zscaler the set it and forget it* command would be to add the Zscaler root certificate to the system java installation.

The question was asked about the problem encountered when running a Windows OS. However the problem is within Java and is OS independent. I run macOS, so you will need to translate the concepts to meet the Windows OS.

In the macOS Keychain you will find the zScaler root certificate. Export that to a .cer file on your system.

- Open Keychain Access
- Search for Zscaler and highlight certificate
- Export certificate (File -> Export Items) File Format Certificate (.cer)

Import this certificate into the Java installation. This will need privileged access and the path to the security/cacerts file may vary slightly.

```
sudo keytool -import -alias zScaler -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file /Users/code/Zscaler_Root_CA.cer
```

*Note: save this root certificate file and the command as this will need to be re-executed each time you upgrade java.